# File copy progress bar not updating. File copy works fine

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have an application I am writing to copy a file. I have the file copying without any issues, but the progress bar is not updating for some reason. I am using the background worker.  Here is the code:

```
private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            // Gets the size of the file in bytes.
            Int64 iSize = strInputFile.Length;

            // Keeps track of the total bytes downloaded so we can update the progress bar.
            Int64 iRunningByteTotal = 0;
                // Open the input file for reading.
            using (FileStream InputFile = new FileStream(strInputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
            {
                // Using the FileStream object, we can write the output file.
                using (FileStream OutputFile = new FileStream(strOutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                {
                    // Loop the stream and get the file into the byte buffer.
                    int iByteSize = 0;
                    byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[iSize];
                    while ((iByteSize = InputFile.Read(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        // Write the bytes to the file system at the file path specified.
                        OutputFile.Write(byteBuffer, 0, iByteSize);
                        iRunningByteTotal += iByteSize;

                        // Calculate the progress out of a base "100."
                        double dIndex = (double)(iRunningByteTotal);
                        double dTotal = (double)byteBuffer.Length;
                        double dProgressPercentage = (dIndex / dTotal);
                        int iProgressPercentage = (int)(dProgressPercentage * 100);
                        // Update the progress bar.
                       bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                        bgWorker.ReportProgress(iProgressPercentage);
                    }
                    // Close the output file.
                    OutputFile.Close();
                }
                // Close the input file.
                InputFile.Close();
            }
        }

        private void bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // We will increase the progress bar when work progress is reported.
            pbCopyProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            pbCopyProgress.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + " %");
        }

        private void bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Disable the Copy button once the file has been copied.
            MessageBox.Show("The file: "+strOutputFile+" has been copied");
            btnCopy.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Comment: This line `bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;` should be outside your `bgWorker_DoWork` method, maybe in your Form's constructor (you usually do this "visually", not programmatically).

Comment: Try replacing your `bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;` in your form constructor

Comment: I have already fixed the bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

Comment: have you added `bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();` method ??

Comment: How can you get the file size from the string filename? (Int64 iSize = strInputFile.Length)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I needed to initialize my background worker event handlers in order to fix the issue I was having. I just needed to add the following three lines in the form load event:

```
 bgWorker.DoWork += bgWorker_DoWork;
 bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
 bgWorker.ProgressChanged += bgWorker_ProgressChanged;
```

Comment: For future reference, you can create Backgroundworker objects and hook-up all the event handlers automatically by using the Visual Studio forms editor - BackgroundWorker is in the Forms toolbox, and works like any other forms control (button, textbox, etc), except that it's not actually visible on the form at runtime.